# Compressing data during spooling from oracle table

Tags: linux, oracle, csv, scripting, oracle-export-dump

We are spooling data into CSV file from oracle table at Linux server.

Using the below code:

```
sqlplus -s Schema_User/Schema_Password@DB_Service <<EOF
set termout off
set heading off
set underline "_"
set pagesize 0 embedded on
set linesize 32000
set LONG 50000
set colsep '"|"'
set feedback off
spool ./Temp/ABC.csv
Select COLUMN1,COLUMN2 from ABC;
spool off
EOF
```

The free space on the Linux server (df -h) is 500GB.

The generation of spool file ABC.csv terminates after reaching the size 500GB.

We suspect that the final size of ABC.csv will be much more than 500GB.

Please suggest a way by which we can compress the data during spool process.

Should I first create a compressed temporary table from the oracle table then spool it?

```
CREATE TABLE XXX COMPRESS FOR QUERY AS SELECT * FROM ABC;
```

Comment: If you need to build a CSV, how can a compressed table help to compress the resulting CSV? One way could be building your CSV in some table, then implement some compression algorithm to create (say) a ZIP file containing the CSV. Another approach could be splitting your CSV in more files and then concatenate them.

Comment: I have modified the code to compress data during spooling:

mknod ./Temp/ABC.csv p
sqlplus -s Schema_User/Schema_Password@DB_Service <<EOF
set termout off
set heading off
set underline "_"
set pagesize 0 embedded on
set linesize 32000
set LONG 50000
set colsep '"|"'
set feedback off
host nohup gzip -c < ./Temp/ABC.csv > /tmp/out1.gz \&
spool ./Temp/ABC.csv
Select COLUMN1,COLUMN2 from ABC;
spool off
EOF

But I need the compressed file in tar.bz2 format and not in gz.
Also I am not sure that the above process will not impact the data.

Comment: sqlcl does automatic CSV formatting, also it lets you run javascript, so you could use a variation of this to compress the data as it goes into the spool https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-tools/commit/e82d6cd2c0585a52dda6523d179a1417652b7cc6

Answer (score 3):

I have modified my code as follows and it is working fine now:

```
mknod ../Temp/ABC.csv p
nohup gzip -c < ../Temp/ABC.csv > ../Files/ABC.gz &
sqlplus -s Schema_User/Schema_Password@DB_Service <<EOF
set termout off
set heading off
set underline "_"
set pagesize 0 embedded on
set linesize 32000
set LONG 50000
set colsep '"|"'
set feedback off
set trimspool on
spool ./Temp/ABC.csv
Select COLUMN1,COLUMN2 from ABC;
spool off
EOF
```

Comment: The above code is working perfectly for .gz extension but we need the compressed archive in .tar.bz2

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your script with definition of `sqlplus` is called `script.sh`. Isn't

```
script.sh | gzip > data.csv.gz
```

what you're looking for?

Comment: Ok then script.sh will generate the ABC.csv file before compressing it gzip > data.csv.gz.

The size of ABC.csv will be more than 500GB, greater than free space on disk.

Comment: @Akatsuki Not really. As far as I understand it `gzip` is taking as input output stream from `script.sh` so there shouldn't be any copy of `data.csv`. That's how pipe works. Right side command is taking output from left side command as a stream without saving or storing it anywhere.

Comment: @Akatsuki Have a look on that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/744257/is-it-possible-to-pipe-from-stdin-to-gzip

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably because you are introducing a TON of trailing spaces by using set linesize 32000 and not trimming.

Add this to your script just before the spool command:

```
set trimspool on
```

Depending on how many columns and the size of the data being extracted, this can significantly reduce the filesize.

Also, you might want to change to set colsep '|' (without the double quotes), just be sure the data you're extracting doesn't contain pipes as well (or use another delimiter)